# Twitter Bootstrap tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded Twitter Bootstrap and included the .js files in the footer. I'm wanting a tooltip to appear when you mouse over an info icon. So I have this code:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/png/info.png" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="blah blah blah">
```

Then I have this script to enable the tooltip:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

But the tooltip doesn't appear how it does on the example page over at Twitter Bootstrap.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

It appears with the default styling from my theme, the interesting thing however is if I download the Twitter Bootstrap plugin on WordPress and enable the Javascript library in the plugin - it works. But the catch however is that the default CSS overrides my CSS on the website.

Hope i've made myself clear.

Any answers greatly appreciated as this has been racking my brain for two days.

Arran

Comment: Can you prepare a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** for us?

Comment: sure - http://jsfiddle.net/Euqbz/

Comment: Erm, are you shure that you know what you do? Including `jQuery` and `Twitter Tooltip` is recommended to let it work ;) Look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15246782/1250044

Comment: Yeah, i've included the bootstrap.js file and the jQuery.js library in my footer.php file...

Comment: Mhh, it's hard to see were your problem sits! Look at my answer, it works as excpected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15246782/1250044 Maybe you've included twitters `Tooltip`-plugin above `jQuery`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    $("img[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Attribute selectors should be applied on elements.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as excpected. Are you shure that you've included `jQuery` and twitters `Tooltip`-plugin (in the correct order)?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/xe5UX/2/

Comment: `<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jQuery.js"></script>`

Comment: @ArranChristopherScott can you provide a link to your homepage?

Comment: The website is on a dev server and is only accessible through my home network, I can provide you with a screenshot of how the tooltips look if you would like, thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful... Just edit your question for that.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg3pld748mvyroa/Screenshot%20from%202013-03-06%2012%3A07%3A57.png?m - I've shared a link on my Dropbox page

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Comment: See when I go in to the bootstrap plugin on wordpress and enable the bootstrap CSS it asks if I want to enable the Javascript libraries also...If I tick that it works...But that overrides my CSS

Answer (score 0):

@Arran I have also the same problem but if I change 'title' to 'data-original-title' Then it works form me.Try to use this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/png/info.png" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="blah blah blah">
```